# Scrapy - Create Additional Items In Pipeline

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

So I currently have 2 pipelines, both are ordered as below.

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'myproject.pipelines.mutatorPipeline': 300,
    'myproject.pipelines.submitDatabasePipeline': 800,
}
```

They execute in the correct order.

1.) The first pipeline is a mutator.

2.) The second is submits the information to the database.

The data correctly gets submitted to the database.

My problems is that sometimes when data reaches my `mutator pipeline` I want to create 'additional' items to pass to my second pipeline.

Currently (without mutations) it looks like this:

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
            #Mutate the item
            return item
```

I cannot however, `return` more than once. I also do not want to create an additional item that starts from the start of pipeline 1.

Many helps in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quickly looking at the docs you could probably create a subclass of `scrapy.item.Item`, that is sort of like a linked list.

Not having touched scrapy much something like this could do it. It might need some modifications but should be enough to get you started.

```
class Myitem(Item):
    my_field = scrapy.Field()

    def __init__(self):
        self.next = None
        super(Myitem,self).__init__()
```

Now your process items can create multiple Items and chain them.

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
        # Mutate the item, get additional my_value
        item.next = MyItem()
        item.next['my_field'] = my_value
        return item
```

Now in your database pipeline you can process each item.

```
def process_item(self, item, ...):
    current = item
    while current:
        # process current
        current = item.next
```

Comment: Always make item a list then loop it. Good idea!